# Как сделать в консоли вывод кода, с которым завершается программа в Си?

Tags: c, консоль, mingw, sublime-text-3, компилятор

Я использую Sublime Text 3 + Min GW для компиляции Си программ. Только в консоли не выводятся коды завершения программ. То есть например в main функции я возвращают значение ноль через return, но компилятор мне об этом не пишет или когда когда пишу exit(^код ошибки^) тоже не выводится. То есть я хочу сделать так, чтобы консоль выводила мне с каким кодом завершается программа, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: вот про sublime тут говорить не стоило, какое отношение имеет к вопросу этот редактор?

Comment: @SonicMyst Некоторые IDE запускают приложения через обертки, которые печатают эти самые коды завершения. Возможно, что на sublime есть (или можно сделать) плагин, который будет это делать. Так что вполне прямое отношение, мне кажется.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вот только сомневаюсь, что консоль запускалась в sublime, если бы это был какой-нибудь atom или vs code, то возможно вполне...Скорее всего консоль запускалась отдельно, тогда sublime тут никакого отношения не имеет. В любом случае тут требуется уточнение от автора, что и как он использовал...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Ваш исполняемый модуль называется *a.out*, то тогда делайте так:

```
./a.out
echo $?
```

Команда *echo* напечатает код завершения Вашей программы.